# how do i add different custom right sidebars with different widths and content on different pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i everyone i have afew pages in wordpress that i need different custom right sidebars on with different css styles. for example i would like my homepage right sidebar to be a set width say 100px  and displaying specific content and id like to have  my special offers page with a right sidebar thats a different width say 230px displaying different content like widgets etc...

to my understanding this should be able to be achieved by creating custom sidebars by registering them with a wordpress function and then creating a custom sidebar template php file with a different css class for the sidebar. and then calling the new custom sidebar template file inside of a custom page template file being applied to a target page in wordpress so that the page loads the custom sidebar template instead of the normal sidebar template with a new css class that can be modified to achieve different sidebar styles for different pages. so i created the following custom sidebar template and called it customrightsidebar.php

```
<div id="sidebar3"><div class="sidebar3"><?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('customright-sidebar') ) : ?><div class="customright-sidebar"><h4>Recent Posts</h4><ul><?php wp_get_archives('type=postbypost&limit=5'); ?> </ul></div><?php endif; ?></div> <br style="clear:both"></div>
```

i then registered a new custom sidebar using this function

```
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'customright-sidebar','before_widget' => '<div class="customright-sidebar">','after_widget' => '</div>','before_title' => '<h4>','after_title' => '</h4>',));
```

and here is the custom page template that is calling the custom sidebar template

```
<?php get_header(); ?><div id="breadcrumb"><?php breadcrumbs(); ?></div>

<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/customrightsidebar.php");?>

<div id="kontenutama"> <div class="postingan2"><?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2><?php the_content(); ?><?php endwhile; else: ?> <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?><br style="clear:both;"></div></div>


<br style="clear:both"><div style="clear:both"></div><?php get_footer()?>
```

i successfully have a custom right sidebar that appears in my wordpress admin panel and i can apply widgets to it in the widgets section of my admin panel i can also see it appear in the custom sidebar dropdown selection menu in my wordpress pages where you would specify your new custom sidebars to overwrite the old ones. you can see a screenshot of the sidebar selection boxes in my theme by visiting this url

http://test.smartphonesource.org/sidebars.png

and normally by selecting it it would overwrite the default sidebars on the page

i have been able to get the custom sidebar template to load with the custom class on the page and ive been able to edit the css but the actual custom sidebar itself with its widgets isnt appearing or overwriting anything even though ive selected it to overwrite the right sidebar of the current page in the custom sidebars selection box

im not sure where to go from here or if there is a different way to do this i think somewhere the customsidebar isnt overwriting the default right sidebar  when its been selected in the custom sidebar selection box on my pages im new to wordpress and php. ive been able to use the customright-sidebar on my videos page for testing and it successfully overwrote the right sidebar and worked but it was running this default right sidebar template

```
<div id="sidebar2"><div class="sidebar2"><?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Right') ) : ?><div class="left-sidebar"><h4>Recent Posts</h4><ul><?php wp_get_archives('type=postbypost&limit=5'); ?> </ul></div><?php endif; ?></div> <br style="clear:both"></div>
```

anyhelp would be greatly appreciated figuring this out =) you can see the homepage of the site here that im using to learn wordpress and from there you can navigate to the videos and special offers page that im tearing apart to get a better  idea of what im trying to do with the sidebars

http://test.smartphonesource.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to fix the page issue im not sure what was wrong but it suddenly started working with the same code i know  i cleared my cache so maybe that was affecting it or preventing the new changes from appearing sometimes if i dont clear the cache after i upload new images they wont display for me

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your website looks really awesome:) And to fix this did you make sure that your page is only grabbing the new sidebar code only?

Comment: thanks for the compliment tyree =) its been pretty fun learning wordpress i was  blown away by its power when i started seeing what some of the plugins are capable of compared to my experience with other platforms. im used to building amazon stores on the associate o matic platform but my sites just didnt have enough flexibility the last site i built on associate o matic was http://cheapcamerasonline.com the sidebar mods are appearing now even though i didnt change the code lol i think it had something to do with me clearing my cache im glad its working now =)

Comment: I am happy that it started working for you=) I run into the same cache problems too. Sometimes you need to empty your cache and do a hard reload. Wordpress is definitely capable of doing ALOT! So next time when you have another question or problem "don't work hard, work smart" and come here and ask a question;)

Comment: thanks for the advice tyree =)  i cant count the times i spent hours tinkering with some code only to find out something  simple was holding me back like the cache lol  im definitely starting to love stack overflow its great to finally find an awesome forum that has so many active  members  ill be sure to fire away with more questions in the future if i get stuck on something thanks for your reply's ill keep the hard reloads in mind and definitely will be clearing my cache more often